# Mamaral onboarding library in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I'm having trouble getting my onboarding System to work. I am using this framework: 
https://github.com/mamaral/Onboard

This demo for the framework only comes in Objective-C, I have done my best to create my own version in Swift and am almost finished but I am stuck on a way to move to another storyboard after the final screen. This is my code at the moment:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    func setupNormalRootViewController() -> Void {

        self.window?.rootViewController = LoginViewController

    }


    let firstPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "Welcome To my App", body: "App Mesage", image: UIImage(named: "heart"), buttonText: "") {}
    let secondPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "...", body: "Message", image: UIImage(named: "Mint"), buttonText: "") {}

    let thirdPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "title", body: "abcd", image: UIImage(named: "Choco"), buttonText: "End", action: { setupNormalRootViewController() } ) {}

    let onboardingVC = OnboardingViewController(backgroundImage: UIImage(named: "blueBackground"), contents: [firstPage, secondPage,thirdPage])




    self.window?.rootViewController = onboardingVC
 }
}
```

I am calling `setupNormalRootViewController` in the `thirdPage` variable but there seems to be no way to move on past the initial onboarding screen even though I have set a specified method to run when pressing the button on the last screen.

Comment: is `setupNormalRootViewController` method called?

Comment: Yes, It is called in the "let thirdPage" variable

Comment: I mean, is it executed? Add breakpoint to the `self.window?.rootViewController = FirstViewController`

Comment: @user1941284 oh. No it is not being executed, action is not taking in the method properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?



func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.




    let firstPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "Welcome To my App", body: "App Mesage", image: UIImage(named: "heart"), buttonText: "") {}
    let secondPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "...", body: "Message", image: UIImage(named: "Mint"), buttonText: "") {}

    let thirdPage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "title", body: "abcd", image: UIImage(named: "Choco"), buttonText: "End") { () -> Void in
        self.setupNormalRootViewController()
    }

    let onboardingVC = OnboardingViewController(backgroundImage: UIImage(named: "blueBackground"), contents: [firstPage, secondPage,thirdPage])


    self.window?.rootViewController = onboardingVC


    return true
}

func setupNormalRootViewController() -> Void {

    self.window?.rootViewController = ViewController()

}
}
```

Comment: This solution returns an error saying " AppDelegate has no member 'setupNormalRootViewController'. This is odd because it is declared right above the function.

Comment: Can you edit the question and paste the code from `AppDelegate`?

Comment: edited now, there is not much outside of what I posted though.

Comment: Put `setupNormalRootViewController ` method below `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

Comment: I just tried code above and it works, please try code above again, and check that `setupNormalRootViewController ` is outside of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.